# Mean distance between alternatively jumping frogs

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk, probabilistic-method

Consider a bounded line in $\mathbb Z$, with the indices $a$ and $b$ as its end-points (with $|a-b| \geq 3$). We place two frogs on the line, starting at $i$ and $j$. At each time step $n$ (discrete) the frogs must alternatively (one jump per time step) make a random jump to one of their neighbours (so either +1 or -1 with equal probability, unless one neighbour is an end-point or the other frog, in which case the frog jumps to its only neighbour with probability one [1]). The only rule is: the frogs can never occupy the same position at the same time. So intuitively this implies that either frog at any given time is only able to explore a small span of the whole line, namely, from one end-point upto the position of the other frog.

[1]: small caveat, it can happen that the frog to jump has no empty neighbour, e.g. when next to an end-point with the other frog blocking its other side), in this case only the other frog can make a jump

Is it possible to determine the mean distance between the two frogs as a function of number of steps and size of the line? Can we establish whether that distance converges towards a stationary value? I'm mainly interested in learning about the methodology to tackle such probability theory questions. So any hints or sources (of similar problems) are welcome.

Comment: Have a look at chapter 4 of the excellent lecture notes (http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/probability/lecturenotes/RandomWalks.pdf)

Comment: This is "almost" a Markov chain $(X_n)$ on $S=\{(i,j)\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\mid a\leqslant i<j\leqslant b\}$ ("almost" because the frog which moves alternates and because of the peculiar moves at the ends of the line). Assuming that when a move is impossible this is counted as a move $a\to a$ or $b\to b$, the processes $(X_{2n})$ and $(X_{2n+1})$ *are* true Markov chains hence, modulo aperiodicity, indeed the distance between them at even times and at odd times both converge in distribution, possibly to the same distribution.

Comment: You noticed that the process considered in my comment is the *pair* of positions. Of course one position alone has few chances of being Markov.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L,R$ be resp. the Left and Right frog.

Let $n$ be the number of possible positions (for example  $n=20$ in the picture at the bottom of this text).

Let $D_n$ be the random variable "distance between frogs". We have:

> $$\tag{1}E(D_n)=\dfrac{n+1}{3}$$

[image]

**Let us prove (1) by induction on the number $n$ of positions.**

It is true for $n=4$ (see "Addendum 1" at the bottom of this text).

Let us assume (1) to be true at step $n$.

Let us prove that $E(D_{n+1})=\dfrac{n+1+1}{3}$, i.e., $E(D_{n+1})=E(D_{n})+\dfrac{1}{3}.$

To each configuration at step $n$ (that one can consider as a binary number with $n$ digits, two of them being "ones", $n-2$ being zero : vacant positions), one can associate 3 configurations at step $n+1$, by inserting a new position (a new zero):

- either in region 1 defined to be on the left of L, or
- in region 2, between L and R, or,
- in region 3, i.e., on the right of R.

The mean width of region 2 is $(n+1)/3$ by the recursion assumption.

The two other regions, by an elementary consideration of symmetry, have the same mean width ; thus the mean width of each region is $(n+1)/3$. In other words, each region has an equal probability of being chosen for the insertion of a new place.

But it is only by inserting in region 2 that the mean distance increases by $1$. Insertion in the two others does not lead to an increase in the mean distance between L and R frogs.

Thus the mean distance increases by steps of $1/3$, proving (1).

**Addendum:**

1)   The case $n=4$ is easily treated by enumeration. There are 6 possible pairs of position :

$$\begin{cases} 
     1  &  2 & \to & D_4=1\\
     1  &  3 & \to & D_4=2\\
     1  &  4 & \to & D_4=3\\
     2  &  3 & \to & D_4=1\\
     2  &  4 & \to & D_4=2\\
     3  &  4 & \to & D_4=1
\end{cases}$$

giving $E(D_4)=\tfrac{5}{3}.$

The important thing is that all these positions have the same stationary probability. For being convinced of that consider the diagram:

[image]

and the associated matrix:

$$\begin{matrix} (a) \\ (b) \\ (c) \\ (d) \\ (e) \\ (f)  \end{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
a & 0 & a & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & a & 0 & 0 & 0 & a \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \ \ \text{with} \ \ a=1/2.$$

This matrix has a unique eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|=1$ which is precisely $\lambda=1$, all the others being such that $|lambda|<1$.  One can verify that, for any $V$, $lim_{n \to \infty} M^nV$ is a vector with identical components, proving the equiprobability of all events in the stationary state.

2) this result has been confirmed by the following Matlab program giving an exact value of $D_n$ by an exhaustive list of elementary events:

> > ```
> > format rat
> > n=6;I=1:n;
> > U=nchoosek(I,2)
> > mean(diff(U'))
> > ```

3) and, for large values of $n$, by the following simulation program that has also produced the graphical representation given upwards:

> > ```
> > function frogs
> > clear all;close all;hold on;grid on
> > n=20;%number of places
> > nt=10000;%number of instants
> > M=[];   
> > LR=sort(ceil(n*(rand(1,2))));
> > L=LR(1);R=LR(2);
> > T=zeros(2,nt);
> > for k=1:nt
> >    T(:,k)=[L;R];
> >    L1=TestL(L,R,n);
> >    R1=TestR(L1,R,n);
> >    L=L1;R=R1;
> > end;
> > a=(nt-100):nt;
> > plot(T(1,a),a,'r','linewidth',1,'linesmoothing','on');
> > plot(T(2,a),a,'b','linewidth',1,'linesmoothing','on');
> > diff(T)
> > M=[M,mean(diff(T))];
> > mean(M)
> > %________________________
> > function Ls=TestL(L,R,n);
> >    if L==1
> >       if R>2
> >          Ls=2;
> >       else
> >          Ls=1;
> >       end;
> >    else
> >       if L+1<R
> >          Ls=L+sign(rand-0.5);
> >       else
> >          Ls=L-1;
> >    end
> > end;
> > %________________________
> > function Rs=TestR(L,R,n);
> >  if R==n
> >     if L<n-1
> >        Rs=n-1;
> >     else
> >        Rs=n;
> >     end;
> >  else
> >     if L+1<R
> >        Rs=R+sign(rand-0.5);
> >     else
> >        Rs=R+1;
> >     end
> >  end;
> > ```

Assumptions: L jumps first (if possible), then R jumps (if possible), being understood that the jump of R can be influenced by the jump L just did.

Comment: There is something that I have not taken into account in a plain way: when you say that frogs jump alternatively, do you mean precisely that **"the Left frog jumps, then the Right frog jumps"** ? In this case, some of the values of distances after jump (more precisely after the 2 jumps of L then R) in the rightmost column of the picture should be (slightly) modified.

Comment: Yes indeed, this is exactly what i meant by alternative jumps. Thanks a lot for your answer, i will study it carefully and gey back to you.

Comment: Dear Jean-Marie, I have written a small script in mathematica that solves it numerically, that will be sufficient for this exercise, I will now move on to other exercises. Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: I on the other hand seem to obtain n+4/3 for large n's, but there may be possibly a bug in my code, I ll double check it.

Comment: $n+4/3$ or $(n+4)/3$ ? If it is this last expression, it is the same as $(n+1)/3$ with a shift $n \to n+1$.

Comment: If $n=4$, the mean distance is $\frac32$ rather than $\frac53$. For tthe reason why, see my comment to @BGM's answer.

Comment: @Did I will have a closer look at your argument. The fact that the Left frog moves first, thus can impact the move of the second frog (see our exchange above with user929304) is maybe a cause of "distortion". I have tried, to my best, to take into account every particular case in my simulation program and I get a result very close to $5/3$. I know that it is not a valid argumentation, but one thing is certain, I do not use a Markovian model as such.

Comment: Slightly related, this problem where the walkers are a cat and a mouse : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/356983

Comment: @Did See my addendum proving by a simple enumeration that the mean distance is $\frac{5}{3}$, not $\frac{3}{2}$ as you were thinking,  for the case $n=4$. Besides, I don't think I deserve a downgrading: I have completely solved the issue with a certain wealth of explanation.

Comment: You are simply remaking the same mistake, which is to believe that at stationarity the pair of positions is uniformly distributed on the set $S$ of possible pairs. The diagram of transitions of the Markov chain on $S\times\{L,R\}$ readily shows it is not, as my comment on @BGM's post explains..

Comment: If $n=5$, the weights of the 20 vertices are all $1/38$, $2/38$ or $4/38$, for a distribution of the distances between the two particles equal to $$\frac1{19}(6\delta_1+8\delta_2+4\delta_3+\delta_4)$$ and a mean distance $D_5$ equal to $$D_5=2$$ At present, we know that $$D_2=1\quad D_3=\frac43\quad D_4=\frac32\quad D_5=2$$

Comment: @Did I have completely re-done the calculations with a diagram showing the different probabilities and the associated transition matrix. I come back to the 5/3; I think that the difference of point of view is that, in this "frogs ballet", there is an assymmetry: it is the left dancer who (is obliged to move first (if he can), then the right dancer is obliged to move by choosing among the remaining places (if he can move).

Comment: 1. There is a serious theoretical mistake in your post, which is to believe that, if $M$ is the transition matrix of an irreducible aperiodic finite Markov chain $X$, then the fact that, for some vector $V$, $\lim M^nV$ converges to some vector with identical entries, says anything at all about the unique stationary distribution $\pi$ of $X$. In fact, $(M^n)_{ij}\to\pi_j$ hence, denoting by $\pi$ the column vector with entries $\pi_i$, $M^nV$ converges to the vector with identical entries $\pi^tV=\sum\limits_i\pi_iV_i$ **for every value of $\pi$**. To identify $\pi$, one usually solves ...

Comment: ... the matrix equation $\pi^tM=\pi^t$. In the present case, one gets that $\pi$ allocates weights proportional to $(1,2,1,2,2,1)$ to the states $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$, thus, $\pi$ is **not uniform**. The states $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ correspond to distances $(D(a),D(b),D(c),D(d),D(e),D(f))=(1,2,3,1,2,1)$ between the pair of occupied vertices hence the expected distance between the pair of occupied vertices with respect to $\pi$ is $$\sum\limits_{x=a}^fD(x)\pi_x=\frac{1\cdot1+2\cdot2+3\cdot1+1\cdot2+2\cdot2+1\cdot1}{1+2+1+2+2+1}=\frac53$$ that is, the value you found, but not for the reason you mention. ...

Comment: ... 2. This computes the stationary distance between the occupied vertices after the moves of the rightmost particle. It happens that the stationary distance between the occupied vertices after the moves of the leftmost particle is the same but this should be justified. Hence the stationary distance between the occupied vertices after any large number of moves, even or odd, is also the same. 3. I made a mistake in my first computation of $\pi$ for $n=4$, the correct distribution of the distance is in the revised comment to @BGM's answer. 4. Since the proven values of the stationary mean ...

Comment: ... distance $D_n$ for $n$ vertices are $$D_2=1\qquad D_3=\frac43\qquad D_4=\frac53\qquad D_5=2$$ the conjecture that, for every $n$, $$D_n=\frac{n+1}3$$ becomes quite plausible. 5. Your approach to the recursion step of the proof of the conjecture seems invalid since, once again, $\pi$ is not uniform. For $n=4$, the positions encoded as you suggest are
$$1100\quad1010\quad1001\quad0110\quad0101\quad0011$$ and their respective weights are
$$\frac19\quad\frac29\quad\frac19\quad\frac29\quad\frac29\quad\frac19$$

Comment: @Did Thanks very much for for all these explanations. I will dwelve into it again in some days, as I'm rather busy now.

Comment: @Did in your earlier comment, how did you calculate the coefficients in $(6\delta_1 + 8\delta_2 + 4\delta_3 + \delta_4)?$ For example I count 20 situations where the distance is $=1,$ for $n=5.$

Comment: @user929304 That may well be (I did not check your counting) but enumerating positions is not enough to deduce the stationary distribution of the Markov chain since each single position can have (and does have) some different weight. (I seem to have made this exact point already several times on this very page.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just a brute force method to solve for the simplest case.

Consider the possible position being $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ only. If we model the pair of positions of the frong like $(X, Y)$, then it is a markov chain. The possible positions of the two frogs is $\displaystyle \binom {4} {2} = 6$ and multiply by $2$ (for the cases whether it is the turn for the left frog or right frog to jump), the total number of states is $12$ in this case. Thus in general for the case with $a, b$ being the end point is $\displaystyle \binom {|a-b|+1} {2} \times 2 = |a-b|(|a-b|+1)$.

The transition matrix in this case is
$$ P = \begin{matrix} (1,2,l) \\ (1,3,l) \\ (1,4,l) \\ (2,3,l) \\ (2,4,l) \\ (3,4,l) \\  (1,2,r) \\ (1,3,r) \\ (1,4,r) \\ (2,3,r) \\ (2,4,r) \\ (3,4,r) \end{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $l, r$ indicate it is the turn for left or right frog to jump.

Starting at the state $k$, the expected number of visits to state $m$ in $n$ steps (not counting the initial state) is
$$ v_{km}^{(n)} = \sum_{q=1}^{n} p_{km}^{(q)}$$
where $p_{km}^{(q)}$ is the $(k, m)$ entries of $P^q$.

The distance between the two frogs, corresponding to the above $12$ states, are $$ D = (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1)$$ 
and thus the mean difference is
$$ \frac {1} {n} \sum_{m=1}^{12} d_mv_{km}^{(n)}$$

So within finite time $n$, this value is affected by the initial state $k$. In long-term, the steady state distribution is just simply $1/12$ for all the states, and taking expectation we have the long run distance being $5/3$.

Comment: Is it 11/6 or 5/3 ?

Comment: Yes... I added 6 number wrongly lol

Comment: at last I have found a proof...  Can you check it ?

Comment: Interestingly, the stationary distribution of the Markov chain on 12 states that you describe is not uniform, rather, the weights of the states 13L, 13R, 23L, 23R, 24L, and 24R, are all equal to twice the weight of each other state. Thus, the stationary distribution of the distance is
$$\frac19(4δ_1+4δ_2+δ_3)$$ instead of the distribution
$$\frac16(3δ_1+2δ_2+δ_3)$$ that you propose. Oddly, the mean distance is the same, that is, $$\frac53$$ with respect to these two distributions.